Problem with setting up MySQL for a Laravel project
I installed Docker Desktop and created a Laravel project using the following command:
composer create-project laravel/laravel test
I also ran this command:
docker compose up 
My docker-compose.yml file contains:
version: "3.9"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.8.3
    # Uncomment below when on Mac M1
    # platform: linux/arm64/v8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

i also changed a part of .env file to
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel-10-task-list
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root


Everything worked, and when I opened the link http://localhost:8080, the SQL login screen appeared. I entered the username and password (root and root), but the following error appeared:
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
i dont know what should i do.

What is adminer images? in General You need network for comunicate, try to see laravel sail for get an example.

@LorenzoBerti Compose automatically creates a network named default for you; see Networking in Compose in the Docker documentation.  Most Compose setups should not need to explicitly mention networks: at all.  In the Compose file in the question, the adminer container could reach the database using the Compose service name mysql as a host name.
